# Pandas DataFrame to JSON with multiple nested categories

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a solution to convert a Pandas DataFrame with 3 subcategories to an JSON output without any lists.

**This is the data-structure I got:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cat1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'cat2': ['BB', 'BB', 'BC', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BC', 'BC'],
    'cat3': ['CC', 'CC', 'CD', 'CD', 'CD', 'CC', 'CD', 'CE'],
    'prod': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P1', 'P4', 'P1', 'P3','P6'],
    'amount': [132, 51, 12, 421, 55, 11, 123, 312]
})
```

**And this is the desired JSON output:**

```
{
"A": {
    "BB": {
        "CC": {
            "P1": 132,
            "P2": 51
        }
    },
    "BC": {
        "CD": {
            "P3": 12
        }
    }
},
"B": {
    "BB": {
        "CD": {
            "P1": 421,
            "P4": 55
        }
    }
},
"C": {
    "BB": {
        "CC": {
            "P1": 11
        }
    },
    "BC": {
        "CD": {
            "P3": 123
        },
        "CE": {
            "P6": 312
        }
    }
}
```

I had several attemts with the `to_json` method and tried to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44750747/1167012) without any luck.

```
def f(x):
    return dict({k:v for k,v in zip(x.prod, x.amount)})

(
    df.groupby(['cat1','cat2', 'cat3'])
      .apply(f)
      .groupby(level=0)
      .apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
      .to_dict()
)
```

`TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19900276/7964527) but I modified the `.ix` to `.iloc`

```
def recur_dictify(frame):
         if len(frame.columns) == 1:
             if frame.values.size == 1: return frame.values[0][0]
             return frame.values.squeeze()
         grouped = frame.groupby(frame.columns[0])
         d = {k: recur_dictify(g.iloc[:,1:]) for k,g in grouped}
         return d
     
recur_dictify(df)
Out[211]: 
{'A': {'BB': {'CC': {'P1': 132, 'P2': 51}}, 'BC': {'CD': {'P3': 12}}},
 'B': {'BB': {'CD': {'P1': 421, 'P4': 55}}},
 'C': {'BB': {'CC': {'P1': 11}}, 'BC': {'CD': {'P3': 123}, 'CE': {'P6': 312}}}}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Nice recursive solution. Could you explain this solution a little bit? I got to check the squeeze function and how works g.iloc[:,1:] exactly?

Comment: @SvenRojek slice the position from 2nd row to the end